# How can we reconcile the many different models in QCD that make inconsistent assumptions/claims?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

For example, we have quark models, shell models, cluster models, etc. which seem to admit to different interpretations regarding nuclear structure and dynamics. Is there a way to resolve the fact that they're somewhat incompatible?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question, I think it's too vague. Can you say exactly which assumptions are needed to reconcile?

Comment: Sure, as one example, the liquid drop model paints a classical fluid picture while others present a shell structure with distinct energy levels and pointlike nucleons. We can do away with a lot of this stuff by just noting that we're making certain choices when approximating the system, overcoming how intractable QCD can be, etc. But there still seems to be some sort of problem when the models contradict and make it hard to extract a unified picture of what nuclear structure looks like, what is true of it, how we should conceptualize it, etc. Does that make at least a little sense?

Comment: The examples you're describing aren't really models of QCD. These are models of nuclear physics, and the models may or may not actually be based on QCD itself.

Comment: We can just leave out the "in QCD" part then?

Comment: You'd probably be better off deleting this question and writing a new one that's specific to nuclear models.  Again, however, asking about reconciling differences between multiple different nuclear models will be too broad (IMO).  Different odels are "tailored" to focus on different properties, and the only way they'd agree would be if they were (effectively) the same model.  A "pure" QCD model in all it's glory would be too complex to extract useful info from.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe this answer of mine to another question may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215353/what-does-an-undefined-formula-in-physics-mean/215509#215509

Comment: I have seen recent efforts in nuclear physics ([like this](http://esnt.cea.fr/Phocea/Page/index.php?id=71)) to turn older nuclear models into a "tower of effective [field] theories".  While the various models/EFTs in this "tower" may have different regimes of validity, when two or more of them are applied to the same analysis in a regime where they all claim to be valid, it would be reasonable to require that they produce compatible results.  Specifying such an analysis and regime would help make this question (or future ones) more answerable.